# Regexp. Как взять IP,Port и отсечь остальное

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть задача: Взять IP и Порт из строки в .csv файле (пример ниже, сначала IP, затем порт)

```
1.33.3.146,9001,,fwioetwg4utghw4ignc,Fast Running Stable Valid,447,reject,1-65535,0
```

Написал Regex, чтобы брать IP,Port, но вместе сэтим забирается так же "1-65535,0", а мне это не нужно.

Regex:

```
\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3},(\d{1,5})
```

Подскажите, что добавить к моему Regex?
Спасибо!

Comment: Вам не нужны регулярки. CSV имеет строго определенный формат, просто разберите его. В простейшем случае можно просто разбить строку по запятой

Comment: Ну раз нужное в самом начале - добавьте в регэксп символ начала строки `^`. А ещё, просто точка в регэкспе - это вот ни разу не символ точки...

Comment: `/(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3},(\d{1,5})(?!\d)/`, [демо](https://regex101.com/r/q6bjhd/1).

Comment: Господа, спасибо! @Akina, Ваше замечание по поводу точки совершенно справедливо, упустил этот момент. Исправил.

Comment: Теоретически после квотирования точки "1-65535,0" должно перестать опознаваться регэкспом.

Comment: PS. А язык-то какой? может, регэкспы-то и не нужны, и достаточно тупо строковых функций, чтобы откусить всё с начала до второй запятой?

Comment: @Akina А мне не кажется, что [`1111111111.33.3.146,900133333333333333333333` это IP-адрес](https://regex101.com/r/jBo5Hs/1). Экранирование точки не полное решение.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Я писал выше насчёт добавления метасимвола начала строки. Если добавить его (и довесить запятую на хвост, получив в итоге шаблон `^(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}),(\d{1,5}),`), должно стрельнуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экранируйте точки, которые не являются метасимволами, находящими любой символ. Испльзуйте [более точный шаблон для IP-адреса](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html):

```
(?<!\d)((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}),(\d{1,5})(?!\d)
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/q6bjhd/3).

**Подробности**

- `(?<!\d)` - сразу перед совпадением не должно быть цифры
- `(` - начало захватывающей подмаски №1
- `(?:` - начало незахватываемой группы, в которой определен диапазон блока IP-адреса:

  - `25[0-5]|` - `25`, после которого следует цифра от `0` до `5`
  - `2[0-4][0-9]|` - `2`, после которого следует цифра от `0` до `4`, а затем одна любая цифра
  - `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?` - `0` или `1` (опционально, 1 или 0 раз), затем 1 или 2 цифры
- `)` - конец группы (подмаски)
- `(?:`  - начало незахватываемой группы (которая будет повторена 3 раза)

  - `\.` - точка
  - `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` - описанный выше шаблон
- `){3}` - 3 повтора
- `)` - конец захватывающей подмаски
- `,` - запятая
- `(\d{1,5})` - захватывающая подмаска №2: 1-5 цифр
- `(?!\d)` - сразу после совпадения не должно быть цифры.